# Notation for maximum over an arbitrary total order

Tags: notation, order-theory, maxima-minima

I feel like this is a question to which I should already know the answer, but my Google searches so far are coming up empty.

Is there a common notation for specifying the maximum/minimum over an arbitrary total order? For example, let's define $\geq^\mathbf{A}$ over $n$-dimensional vectors by $\mathbf{v} \geq^\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}'$ iff $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v'}) \geq^{lex} \mathbf{0}$.

If I then want to find the maximal vector according to $\geq^\mathbf{A}$ over some set $V$, is there some canonical/common notation for specifying this element?

I've was thinking of using $\max^{\geq^\mathbf{A}}_{\mathbf{v} \in V} \mathbf{v}$ or $\max_{\substack{\geq^\mathbf{A} \\ \mathbf{v} \in V}} \mathbf{v}$, but if there's a canonical way of specifying this, I'd prefer to use that.

Comment: The $\max$ operator generally takes a set (rather than a function) as an argument.  Specify the set sufficiently, and there should be no ambiguity.  For example $$\max\{ v \mid v \in (V, \ge^A)\},$$ where $(V,\ge^A)$ is the ordered set you are considering.  I think that $\max (V,\ge^A)$ would also be unambiguous, or even $\max V$, assuming that there are no other total orders running around.

Comment: @Xander Thanks, that's helpful! I hadn't seen the $(V, \geq^A)$ notation for  ordered sets before. That's definitely a lot nicer than the multiple super- and subscripts. (I'd consider this question answered by this comment - not sure what to do about that since I'm new here!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the $\max$ operator takes a set as its argument.  For example, the maximum value attained by a function $f$ is the maximum of the set of values attained by $f$ over its domain.  If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then this is denoted
$$ \max \{ f(x) \mid x\in\mathbb{R} \}. $$
A common *shorthand* for this is to write
$$ \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}} f(x)
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\max f(x), $$
where the second notation might be used if the domain is understood or otherwise unambiguous.  Additionally, if a set has some extra structure, we can use a tuple to represent the set-plus-structure.  For example, a metric space consists of a set $X$ and a metric $d$, which can be written as $(X,d)$.  Hence it is reasonable to write
$$ (V, \ge^A) $$
for a totally ordered set $V$, where the order is given by $\ge^A$.

Combining these ideas, there are several natural notations which seem reasonable in the context of the question:

- A rather pedantic notation might be
  $$ \max\left\{ v \ \middle|\  v \in \left(V,\ge^A\right) \right\}. $$
- Less pedantically, but retaining all of the important data, we could write
  $$ \max \left(V, \ge^A\right)
  \qquad\text{or}\qquad
  \max_{v \in (V,\ge^A)} v. $$
  Personally, I think that the first notation is likely the best of all those discussed in this answer.  The second notation is meant to parallel the notation for the maximum of a function over some domain, though I don't much like it (the subscript is overly complicated and small).
- Finally, if we are not worried about specifying the total order, we can just write
  $$ \max V. $$
  This might be a very convenient notation if there are no extra total orders running around.